How to create array of dates starting from today to next six dates?
I want an array of dates starting from today to next six days, so it must contain an object representing the which day like monday.. and date in 2-dgit number
const date = new Date();
let option = {
    weekday: 'long',
    day: '2-digit'
};
let date_details = date.toLocaleDateString('en-US', option).split(' ');
let dataslot = [
    {
        day: date_details[0], //'Wednesday',
        date: date_details[1] //'29'
    }
];

This is an example for one day, but i expect till next 6 six days
How do i get the next six days from today in that format ?

To generate an array of dates starting from today to the next six days with each object representing the day of the week and the date in two-digit format, you can use the following approach:


const date = new Date();
let options = {
    weekday: 'long',
    day: '2-digit'
};
let dataslot = [];

// Function to add days to the current date
function addDays(date, days) {
    let result = new Date(date);
    result.setDate(result.getDate() + days);
    return result;
}

// Loop to create the array of date objects for the next 6 days
for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    let nextDate = addDays(date, i);
    let dateDetails = nextDate.toLocaleDateString('en-US', options).split(' ');
    dataslot.push({
        day: dateDetails[0], // 'Wednesday',
        date: dateDetails[1]  // '29'
    });
}
console.log(dataslot)




You don't want to create new Date object for each iteration. Checkout this


let date_slots = [];
let option = {
    weekday: 'long',
    day: '2-digit'
};
const date_object = new Date(); // single date object

for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
  if(i != 0) date_object.setDate(date_object.getDate() + 1);
  
  let [day,date] = date_object.toLocaleDateString('en-in', option).split(' ');
  date_slots.push({
    day,
    date
  })
}

console.log(date_slots)




The post given by jonrsharpe provides the idea on how to acheive your requirement. To be more specific, refer the code below.


const getNextSixDays = () => {
    const days = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'];
    const dateArray = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        const date = new Date();
        date.setDate(date.getDate() + i);
        const day = days[date.getDay()];
        const dateInTwoDigit = String(date.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
        dateArray.push({ day: day, date: dateInTwoDigit });
    }

    return dateArray;
}

console.log(getNextSixDays());




Thank you very much, i don't know why one down vote?
